# Running nginx in rails automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am using rails 2.3.9, rubygems 1.8.24, ruby 1.9.3 and Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit

I just installed nginx as my web server through passenger. Now I want to run nginx as my default server such that when i run ruby script/server, it runs instead of the default WeBrick. Is there any way to do this? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't work the way you described. Once it is started, you won't need to run `script/server`, the rails app will be run at the same time when the Nginx/Apache started.

So, just deploy your rails app following the 'Passenger' manual( in development mode), and you will get your app always running.

so, as conclusion, we can tell that, when deploying a Rails app,  Nginx and Apache is in the same group( work together with Passenger), and Mongrel/Webrick/Thin is another group(`script/server` approach).

Comment: oh, okay. thanks for your answer. I have another question though. Can I at least have nginx show me errors when there are errors in my app? just like Mongrel/Webrick/Thin does? Is it possible?

Comment: You may `tail` the nginx log file perhaps.

Comment: @AldrinDelaCruz: sure. the log file of "Nginx" lies in `/var/log` folder, and the log file of "passenger" lies in `log` folder of your Rails app, just like "Mongrel/Thin".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman).